# Why is WaitForSeconds causing my sprite to be changed?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

In my game, I play an animation, wait for the animation to end, and then I change the sprite image. Next I fade the sprite out, wait for the fade to end, then I disable the gameObject. Here's the code:

```
IEnumerator UnlockSequence()
{
    anim.Play("unlock");
    unlocking = false; // stops UnlockSequence from being called again
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.7f);

    sr.sprite = sprite1; //change sprite

    StartCoroutine(FadeTo(0.0f, 2.0f)); 
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);

    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

IEnumerator FadeTo(float aValue, float aTime)
{
    float alpha = sr.color.a;
    for (float t = 0.0f; t < 1.0f; t += Time.deltaTime / aTime)
    {
        Color newColor = new Color(sr.color.r, sr.color.g, sr.color.b, Mathf.Lerp(alpha, aValue, t));
        sr.color = newColor;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

This works great, except when I get to `yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);` the sprite image goes back to the one it was originally, before the animation. I have no clue why this happens. I know that `sr.sprite = sprite1;` works because when I take out `yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);` the sprite is the correct one. Any help to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is a gif of the problem, I'm sorry for it's terrible quality, but hopefully you can see the problem.

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS2nx.gif)

Comment: I don't know why sprite happend , but I thought you don't need use `WaitForSeconds(2f)` just replace it to`yield return FadeTo(0.0f, 2.0f);` and remove  `StartCoroutine(FadeTo(0.0f, 2.0f)); `

Comment: The fact you disable the game object after this makes me wonder if you have 2 sprites in the same place and it only appears to revert in fact when you destroy the game object revealing the one underneath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely not `WaitForSeconds` which changes the sprite but your `Animator`!

### Reason

If somewhere in any of the `AnimatorState`s you have only **one single keyframe** for a certain property (like in your case apparently the `Sprite`) the `Animator` gains full control over this property and you can **not overwrite it via a script** anymore!

Further the `AnimatorState` has an option `Write Defaults` to which UnityTechnologies said in [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/mecanim-default-values.266613)

> In 5.0 we have added a property on the State to `Write back default values`. Meaning that if turned on, it will write back the **default values** of all animated properties ( on a Controller wide-basis) that are **not animated** in that State.
>
> By default, its "on", so we don't change the behavior that we had before.
>
> So if you want the **non-animated** properties of a State to **keep the value** it had previously, simply **turn it off**.

What it means is that for every property that in this AnimatorState has **no keyframes** it uses the default value which the object would have if there was no `Animator` on it.

### One Solution

So if you want your `Default` state to not overwrite the `Sprite` since there is no keyframe for the `Sprite` in that state then simply turn of this option.

---

### Pure Animator Solution

However, I think you could setup your Animator in a way it could actually handle the entire thing without you needing your script except for starting the animation once.

You say your Animator setup looks like

> Entry → Default ← Unlock

So allow me to ask:

1. Why not simply remove that transition back to `Default`? This would make it stay in the `unlock` state until you tell it otherwise. By having the `Loop Time` turned of as you already have this means it stays at the last keyframe and wouldn't jump back to defaults anyway.
2. Why not simply include the fading-out into your `unlock` animation itself as well? Simply set keyframes for the `color` property as well. This way you wouldn't need to use a script for that.
3. Alternatively if you want to control Fading independently from the (un)lock you could use multiple [Animation Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationLayers.html)! On the main layer you do your (un)locking. On a different layer you do the Fading via the `Color` property.

In general I would usually suggest an Animator setup using `bool` [Animation Parameters](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html) for transitions. Then using multiple layers it could lok like

```
parameters 
   Bool "Open"
   Bool "FadeOut"

layers
    Base Layer

    Entry       -------------------> StateClosed
    StateClosed --(if Open==true)--> AnimOpening
    AnimOpening --(Exit time 1)----> StateOpen
    StateOpen   --(if Open==false)-> AnimClosing
    AnimClosing --(Exit time 1)----> StateClosed

    FadeingLayer (make sure to set Weight to `1` -  its `0` by default)

    Entry          -----------------------> StateFadedIn
    StateFadedIn   --(if FadeOut==true)---> AnimFadingOut
    AnimFaidingOut --(Exit time 1)--------> StateFadedOut
    StateFadedOut  --(if FadeOut==false)--> AnimFadingIn
    AnimFadingIn   --(Exit time 1)--------> StateFadedIn
```

If you want to go sure set keyframes for all according properties in all of the states including the single keyframe states. Meaning e.g. in the FadingLayer you set

```
StateFadedIn: Color.a = 1
StateFadedOut: Color.a = 0
AnimFadingOut: Color.a = well your keyframes here ;)
AnimFadingIn: Color.a = well your keyframes here ;)
```

and the BaseLayer the same way.

This way the `Animator` can not mess it up when force jumping between states via script.

And then in code rather simply set

```
anim.SetBool("Open", true);
```

and then

```
anim.SetBool("FadeOut", true);
```

Finally instead of the last script call you could enhance this even more setting up [Animation Events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html) that automatically invoke the `FadeOut` change when done. You could then still control it as well via script but wouldn't have to "manually" wait until the unlock animation is done before starting the fadeout.

---

I know this is a lot of information but I hope the idea gets clear and you can make your way through the documentation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the animation however my theory would be that your Animation is looping back or causing the sprite to reset to its original sprite.  The Animator replicates the properties of the GameObject based on the state they were in the timeline when the keyframes were created.  I just replicated your code everything is working as expected (wait's 1.5 seconds, changes sprite, fades out after 2.0 seconds and go inactive).  The only thing I didn't have is the animation clip you are using.  When I have a bit of time later I can verify by adding an animation but I would look at that.  If you could share a screenshot of the AnimationClip that would be helpful.

Comment: Obviously the animation is working but it looks like it is switching back to the first frame of the animation or the sprite you are switching to is a closed lock.  What are you trying to switch the sprite to?  Are you trying to switch to a sprite of an open lock then fade out?  If so why don't you just stop the original sprite on the last frame of the animation  (you can turn off loop time in Animation Clip in the Project window and it should stop on last frame) and get rid of the sprite switch all together

Comment: I had already disabled loop time a while ago, and just getting rid of the sprite switch now doesn't change anything (as expected). I can't get it to stop on the last frame, otherwise it would be fine. Maybe the problem is with my animator, which looks like:     Entry -> Default <- Unlock . Default has None as the motion, and Unlock has my "unlock" animation clip as the motion.